# Can I record a Skype call (audio and voice) using a Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, skype, call-recording

I've tried using various call recording apps, and standard voice recording, but none do the job.

I need to record **both sides** of a Skype call made on my Android phone. Unfortunately time is short and I need to do this in a couple of hours, any advice appreciated.

Comment: This site isn't built for fast turnaround on answers. Quite the opposite, really. We want questions and answers that will be useful for quite some time going forward.

Comment: Not a law expert, do the recording and "you must notify the other party" rules (vary by local laws) apply to Skype calls?

Answer (score 2):

This probably is too late to be of help to the OP, but this question is valid and could be useful for others.

Found this: http://community.skype.com/t5/Video-INACTIVE/Record-video-calls-windows/m-p/3012#M44 but it pertains to windows and not the phone environment.

Unfortunately on android, Skype itself would have to have this feature for the best overall success.

Related topics with good answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5382212/capture-video-of-androids-screen
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3176555/android-capture-screen-of-phone-as-a-movie
- Direct link: [Droid@Screen](http://blog.ribomation.com/droid-at-screen/)

An on-phone solution to recording audio would have to simultaneously record incoming mic audio (from you) and outgoing speaker audio (from other). However, you could simply record the stream externally and use a movie/video editor to synchronize the video and audio streams.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with recording is dependent on the kernel if that kernel has the capability to do so within the audio hardware driver!

That aside, another aspect, this governs actual phone calls, is that audio is a mutually exclusive thing, lift handset, audio, speaker is routed to respective hardware pieces, if not in call, audio and speaker gets routed to speaker (combine that with headset and  another route is made!)

Now I do not know if that principle applies to VOIP over wifi (as have never tried it!)

Another thing, depending on where you are, this will be dependent on jurisdiction of your country, two way recording could be seen as illegal and may/could be equivalent to wire-tapping, IANAL!

Check first, if that's "ok to do", then check with the party involved first if they actually mind being recorded, if not, then you could end up in trouble for *invasion of privacy and recording their conversation without their consent*

I am loosely saying that as its a questionable thing to do and do not know legalese but its something to bear in mind.